# Why nodeJS is not working on macOS Monterey?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

Why is Control Center on macOS Monterey listening on port 5000 ? I'm using nodeJS for a work project and I cannot start node on the default port (indeed 5000).

Comment: Why not just use another port while developing? Node doesn't need port 5000 specifically. It should be easy to make it configurable if not already.

Answer (score 8):

I found out a solution !
Just disable "Airplay Receiver" in "System Preference" -> "Sharing" and the port 5000 will be released again.
For some reason in Monterey Airplay Receiver use the same 5000 port of nodeJS.
[Airplay Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs3Kp.png)

Comment: Node.js does not "use" any port. If anything most node projects tend to use port 3000 but again that is not caused by node.js, it is the decision of the people who wrote the code for those projects. It is **your code** that is using port 5000.

Comment: Agree 100% but 99% o the time a default node project starts on port 5000 and I tought that this post could be useful to someone :)

Comment: What do you mean default node project? Node.js defaults to an empty folder for its projects. Try creating a project, run `npm init`. It only creates a package.json file. The reason node does not use any ports by default for its projects is because it does not assume you will be writing a network server. A lot of my projects are just scripts that scans the filesystem and process some files. Most examples of node.js projects you can download online use port 3000, not 5000 (personally I don't know why, people should use port 8080 as the default example of http servers)

Comment: Perhaps the title of the question would be more accurate as "Why are Arteco Global projects not working on Mac OS Monterey"?

Comment: It's very normal to have projects that run on different ports - especially if you're developing in a micro / mini service architecture.
8080 / 8000 are default ports for backend services, 3000 / 4000 / 5000 are all very common for nodejs servers hosting frontend locally.
Sure you can change the port but it is reasonable to be confused by a new system service running on one of these ports, even if it is reasonable for the new system service to be running there.

Answer (score -1):

This question is irrelevant to node and mostly waste peoples time who are actually facing the problem of node not being able to run on Monterey. Should be deleted.